# Two images before running the application in cocos2d app

Tags: ios, ipad, cocos2d-iphone, launch

In xCod i can add one images in "launches images".
How to add two images before running the application?

Answer (score 0):

Launch Images are not supposed to be splash screen for your cocos2d app. See the descriptions in [iOS Human Interface Guidelines: Custom Icon and Image Creation Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html):

> To enhance the user’s experience at application launch, you must provide at least one launch image. A launch image looks very similar to the first screen your application displays. iOS displays this image instantly when the user starts your application and until the app is fully ready to use. As soon as your app is ready for use, your app displays its first screen, replacing the launch placeholder image.
>
> ... Remember, the launch image is not meant to provide an opportunity for artistic expression; it is solely intended to enhance the user’s perception of your app as quick to launch and immediately ready for use.

I think what you need is a new scene in cocos2d. Create a custom CCLayer class, for example SplashLayer, and wrap it in a CCScene to display your two images in whatever sequence and/or form. You can use animations to make the presentation look better. Or you can also create separate scenes for the two images and use transitions to present them in certain order and effect.

However you still gonna need launch images. Just use the first image that you want to show, so that the launch image and splash scene will be connected seamlessly when user starts the app.